# Can JPA/Eclipselink allows use genertic type entity as target relationship attribute?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, one-to-many, many-to-one

Can i use generic type as target entity like in this example?
I get error

Exception Description: [class Node] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.String] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field nodeContent].

first entity:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Node <NodeType extends Node<?, ? >, NodeContentType extends NodeContent<NodeType>> extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_NODE_ID")
    protected NodeType parentNode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentNode", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    protected List<NodeType> children; 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "NODE_CONTENT_ID")       
    protected NodeContentType nodeContent;
}
```

and other entity

```
@Entity
public abstract class NodeContent<NodeType extends Node<?, ? >> extends BaseEntity{ 

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "nodeContent")
protected NodeType node;    
}
```

base entity contains only id, and uuuid.

Comment: How would you expect this mapping to be represented in a database? It would be clearer if you explained your intent

Comment: I think i overdesign it, i ca do everything i want in this case without any generics, base only on abstract entities and extends.